# Snap.svg Animate rotation with circular motion

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to animate a rotation around a point. The problem I'm having is that, even though the end position of the object is correct, the motion of the object to get there is not circular.

Here is the code snippet. Click on the image to run the animation.

```js
var origin = Snap('#origin');
var pointer = origin.select("#pointer");

const paper = document.getElementById("origin");
paper.addEventListener("click", () => {
  pointer.transform('r0,120,172');
  pointer.animate({
    transform: "R90,120,172"
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="origin" height="100mm" width="100mm">
          <g
             id="layer1">
            <circle
               r="45"
               cy="172"
               cx="120"
               id="circle"
               style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" />
            
            <path
               id="pointer"
               d="m 125,182.3622 -10,0 5,-55 z"
               style="color:#000000;clip-rule:nonzero;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;opacity:1;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;color-interpolation:sRGB;color-interpolation-filters:linearRGB;solid-color:#000000;solid-opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;color-rendering:auto;image-rendering:auto;shape-rendering:auto;text-rendering:auto;enable-background:accumulate" />
          </g>
</svg>
```

It makes sense to me, since a transformation only specifies the desired end position, but nothing in between.

Interestingly, this example here: 
http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animategroup 
seems to work just fine. But I don't see the difference.

What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to make a circular rotation animation with Snap.svg?

Comment: Nothing happens in the code here, but are you using the latest version of Snap ?

Comment: I am using the latest version. It's in the code snippet. What do you mean by "nothing happens"? I just tried it in Chrome. Click on "Run code snippet", and then click on the drawing.

Comment: Try 0.5.2 at https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/dev/dist/snap.svg.js