# Why does this snap.svg rotation animation work in JSFiddle but not locally?

Tags: snap.svg

This rotation animation works fine in [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tuqbf9ub), but when I try it locally, it won't animate. If I change the animation from a 360 degree rotation to a 180 degree rotation, it works, sort of, but then it does a strange compound translation and rotation. It's not like the center of rotation is just in the wrong spot. I'm using the same CDN as in the animation. [Others have had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235605/snap-svg-animate-rotation-with-circular-motion), but their problems were not solved.

```js
var s = Snap("#svg");

var c = s.circle(100,100,100).attr({ stroke: 'red', strokeDasharray: "40 280", fill: 'none', strokeWidth: 20 });

function anim() {
    c.transform('r0,100,100');
    c.animate({ transform: "r360,100,100" }, 1000, mina.linear, anim);
};

anim();
```

```html
<body>
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="800"></svg>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.1.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you using 0.1.0 for Snap, it's currently at 0.5.2 like the comment in the other thread  suggests.

Comment: @Ian I'm using the old version because I'm sticking with somebody else's unedited example. Also, the newer version doesn't solve the problem. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Only the version issue, it sounds like you are using a different version, hence the comment, but naturally I can't be sure of what you are using locally and you suggest otherwise (it sounds like you are using 0.5.1). I would probably grab this file https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/dev/dist/snap.svg-min.js which is 0.5.2 place it in the same folder as your html and reference it locally and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: The minified version of 0.5.2 has some kind of a merge conflict marker in it that prevents it from working. The non-minified version runs. It still doesn't solve the animation problem. The animation example is like 10 years old. It worked back then, and it works on JSFiddle now, and it works when you run it as a code snippet on this site, but when I try to deploy it locally, the animation does not work properly.

Comment: Do you get any error at all in console log ? It'd be tempted to post the whole file that someone can try locally. It all works fine locally for me. What browser are you using ?

Comment: It started working when I moved my JS snippet into <script> tags in the HTML file. Also, it works up to version 4.1 of Snap. Now it works both when the snippet is in a separate file, and when it is consolidated into the HTML file.

Comment: Also, there weren't any errors in the console log.